# Passing array by reference

Tags: arrays, perl

I have written a simple Perl program (**Driver.pl**) that passes the `array by reference` and calls the subroutine **add** in `calculate.pm` module.

The calculate.pm module pushes two values 100 and 500 into the array.

When I print the array in Driver.pl file, it prints nothing.

Driver.Pl file:

```
use calculate;
our @my_array;
sub init() {
    $x = 1;
    calculate::add($x, /@my_array);
}
init();
for (@my_array) {
    print $_; #Prints Nothing.
}
```

---

#### calculate.pm

```
sub add() {
    my ($x, @arr) = @_;
    push (@arr, 100);
    push (@arr, 200);
}
1;
```

Comment: calculate::add($x,/@my_array); should be calculate::add($x,\@my_array);

Comment: why do you need `$x` inside `add()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, here is the code you actually want:

File `Calculate.pm`:

```
package Calculate;

sub add {
  my ($x, $arrayref) = @_;
  push @$arrayref, 100, 200;
}

1;
```

File `Driver.pl`:

```
use Calculate;

my @array;

sub init {
  Calculate::add(1, \@array);
}

init();

foreach (@array) {
  print "$_\n";
}
```

What did I do? Well, I fixed all the (syntax-)errors:

- The reference operator is `\` nor `/`.
- Loops are `for` or `foreach` but never `for each`. There is an `each` function that allows us to iterate over collections, but that isn't useful here.
- Don't use prototypes like `()`, unless you know *exactly* what they do, what they mean, and why you *have* to use them here.
- Put an explicit package declaration into your library files.

Then there are some severe style issues:

- Name your packages with uppercase names – lowercase names are reserved for “pragmas”.
- Declare all variables with `my`, unless you really need global/dynamic variables. You don't.

And a newline after `print` can't hurt.

In our `add` function, we receive an array reference. (If you know C++: Perl references are like pointers, not like C++ references). References are scalars, so we put it into `$arrayref`. To get the actual array, we *dereference* it like `@$arrayref` – but don't do a copy, or you aren't manipulating the original.

You could *slurp* the remaining arguments into an array, like `my ($x, @list) = (1, 2)` puts `2` into the array. But in your case, the `2` is an array reference! Therefore the `@list` contains a single element which is our array reference – but it isn't the same array.

This still isn't elegant code and has architecture problems, but it should now at least compile.

Comment: Its works good. Thanks a ton. Sorry for numerous typos. I typed the code in s.o. editor directly instead of writing and compiling on my local machine first.

Answer (score 4):

This will work as expected. I have removed module for ease of debug.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


our @my_array;
init();
foreach(@my_array)
{
  print $_; #Prints Nothing.
}

sub init
{
   my $x=1;
   add($x,\@my_array); # Note the backward slash - This is how reference is passed.
}



sub add
{
   my ($x,$arr)=@_;
   push (@{$arr},100); # Note how array is referenced.
   push (@{$arr},200);   
}
```

Using     `use strict;` and  `use warnings;` is a good practice

Comment: Its works good. Thanks a ton. Sorry for numerous typos. I typed the code in s.o. editor directly instead of writing and compiling on my local machine first.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the typos are just errors in copying the code here (e.g. `/@my_array` should be `\@my_array`), you need to take an array *reference* in `add()`, not an array:

```
sub add(){
   my ($x, $arr) = @_;
   push (@$arr,100);  # or push( @{ $arr }, 100 );
   push (@$arr,200);
}
```

Comment: Its works good. Thanks a ton. Sorry for numerous typos. I typed the code in s.o. editor directly instead of writing and compiling on my local machine first.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub init {
   $x=1;
   calculate::add($x,\@my_array);
}
```

---

```
sub add {
   my ($x,$arr) = @_;
   push (@$arr,100);
   push (@$arr,200);
}
1;
```

Comment: Its works good. Thanks a ton. Sorry for numerous typos. I typed the code in s.o. editor directly instead of writing and compiling on my local machine first.